# Is there a Bayesian filter library for .NET

Tags: .net, bayesian

Is there a Bayesian filter library for .NET?

I would like to setup a group of folders and have emails automatically moved to those folders based on what has been previously moved to the folder.

If you are familiar with FogBugz auto-sort, that's exactly what I would like to do.

Comment: I don't have the ability to edit your post, but the auto-sort functionality you mentioned is documented here:
http://www.fogcreek.com/FogBugz/Downloads/KamensPaper.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [Weka.Net](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wekadotnet) which is a port of the [Weka Java Machine Learning Framework](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/) to .NET. It is an alpha release, and seems not so active, but if it has the core of Weka, you can use it to write what you ask for.
[Mailprobe](http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/mailprobe/) "does support N categories, not just Spam/NonSpam" - so maybe this is what you are looking for. This [naive bayesian classifier](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/BayesClassifier.aspx) may be helpful too.

Answer (score 1):

This totally doesn't answer your question but the product called [Popfile](http://getpopfile.org/) does this using a Perl library.